# How to set env with dashes?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl

How to set env with dashes?

I execute the command:

```
kubectl set env deployment/service "--cron.updates=0 */10 8-9 * * *"
```

And get error:

> Error: unknown flag: --cron.full-update-check-status See 'oc set env
> --help' for usage.

How to add environment to service with dashes?

Comment: Typically I'd edit the YAML file that launched the deployment, commit it to source control, and run `kubectl apply -f` to update it.  I'd avoid commands like `kubectl set` or `kubectl edit` that make changes in-cluster without tracking them elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution-1:**

Use single quotes

```
kubectl set env deployment/foo  -- "--cron.updates='0 */10 8-9 * * *'"
```

This would change the `env` of the `pod` to:

```
k exec -it foo-78fff84996-5mskb -- printenv |grep cron.updates
--cron.updates='0 */10 8-9 * * *'
```

**Solution-2:**

Disable `glob` , which would prevent use of single quotes.

You may disable `glob` and do the following:

```
set -f #disable glob
kubectl set env deployment/foo  -- "--cron.updates1=0 */10 8-9 * * *"
set +f #enable glob
```

This would also work, example output:

```
k exec -it foo-5d4998668b-6gc9j  -- printenv |grep cron.updates
--cron.updates='0 */10 8-9 * * *'
--cron.updates1=0 */10 8-9 * * *
```